# xdebug is not installed in xamp. Nothing in phpinfo

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

So I have netbeans installed and xampp. Before I formatted they both worked perfectly together and I just installed them nothing else.

So now I am really annoyed as I have spent the whole day looking for what is wrong and found NOTHING!

So my first step is to check I have one php.ini file and I do.
Then nest step was checking xdebug existed and it does at : `C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll`

I then changed the ini file to the current settings:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\tmp"
```

I understand that not all of them are necessary, however, looking through so many questions they all appeared relevant.

Then NOTHING changes after stopping and restarting the apache server.

I then go to http://xdebug.org/wizard.php to see if this can shed any lights by throwing on my situation about mabey a new birary I should install and the response I get includes nothing about what to download!

```
Tailored Installation Instructions

Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.16
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\ext
Instructions

Download
Move the downloaded file to "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\ext"
Edit C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\ext\"
Restart the webserver
```

I have netbeans 7.3.1 and php 5.4.16 and I am also running my XAMPP controller and netbeans in admin mode as well.

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the Difference Between Extension and zend\_extension in php.ini?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758014/whats-the-difference-between-extension-and-zend-extension-in-php-ini)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download:

[x86](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll)

I had the same problem with a wrong version.

Comment: What I do not understand is that I was using exactly the same .dll except I used the 64 bit version and that did not work. Why would this be as I am running a 64bit OS

Comment: I noticed the (x86) in your Program Files, the application itself is 32 bit. It doesn't matter if your OS is 32 or 64 since your version of PHP is 32.

Comment: It doesn't work with PHP 7.3.0 latest Xampp. Can anyone help?